# Hosting a game on a server

Tags: javascript

I have the following code but it's a bit messy and hard to look at. I could include a function to host a game so that block of code isn't repeating, but could this be optimized any further?

```
server.em.addListener('hostGame', function(settings)
{
    if (Object.keys(hostingGames).length != 0) //If nobody is hosting a game
        {
            for (i in hostingGames) //If there is more than 1 game being hosted, scroll through each one
            {
                if(hostingGames[i].userId === settings.userId) //Check if any of them are by the current user
                {
                    break; //if there is, dont let them host a new one
                }
                else
                {
                    var hostGame = new HostGame(); //If the player isnt hosting a game, host a new game for them

                    hostGame.initialise(settings.userId, settings.userName, settings.boardSize, settings.gameMode, settings.gameNote);
                    hostingGames[settings.userId] = hostGame;
                    server.consoleLog('APP', settings.userName + ' is hosting a game. ID: ' + settings.userId);
                    server.updateGamesList(hostingGames);
                }
            }
        }
        else //If there is no games being hosted, the user must not be hosting any, so let them host a new game
        {
            var hostGame = new HostGame();

            hostGame.initialise(settings.userId, settings.userName, settings.boardSize, settings.gameMode, settings.gameNote);
            hostingGames[settings.userId] = hostGame;
            server.consoleLog('APP', settings.userName + ' is hosting a game. ID: ' + settings.userId);
            server.updateGamesList(hostingGames);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

- Your indents could use a little work.
- Typical JS use the collapsed braces or "egyptian braces", where the opening brace is on the same line as the opening statement.
- Use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct strings.
- Comments be their own line. That way, they're readable from the very start and don't run off to the right.
- Do the "early return" pattern, where you return on invalid cases until you can assume validity. That way, you avoid deeply nested conditions.

Here's a more concise version:

```
server.em.addListener('hostGame', function(settings){

  // Get essential values. You can inline them, but I prefer putting them in
  // variables for clarity.
  const gameKeys = Object.keys(hostingGames);
  const gameUids = gameKeys.map(key => hostingGames[key].userId);
  const userHasGame = gameUids.includes(settings.userId);

  // The only time the code ever bails out is when the user has a game.
  if(userHasGame) return;

  // userHasGame can also be false if there are no games since gameKeys will
  // be empty, causing gameUids to be empty, causing includes to be false.

  // Otherwise, a game is created.
  const hostGame = new HostGame();
  hostGame.initialise(settings.userId, settings.userName, settings.boardSize, settings.gameMode, settings.gameNote);
  hostingGames[settings.userId] = hostGame;
  server.updateGamesList(hostingGames);

  server.consoleLog('APP', `${settings.userName} is hosting a game. ID: ${settings.userId}`);
});
```